# How can I inspect the contents of a static thread_local variable on a heap dump with windbg?

Tags: c++, windbg, thread-local-storage

Given the following source code:

```
namespace EventThreadLocal {

  static thread_local std::unique_ptr<std::vector<EventInfo>> Stack;

  static const EventInfo* Top()
  {
    auto stack = Stack.get();
    if (!stack)
      return nullptr;
    if (stack->empty())
      return nullptr;

    return &(stack->back());
  }
}
```

How can I inspect the contents of the static thread_local variable Stack on a heap dump?

My understanding is that the command !tls displays the thread local storage slots, but how can I know the appropriate slot index used by this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need know the TLS slot associated the the `static thread_local` variable, the debugger already resolves that with `x` command. See below sample output that `x` resolves `Stack` to different addresses for different threads in WinDbg.

```
0:000> x test_exe!Stack
00000296`a5437410 test_exe!Stack = empty
0:000>~1s
0:001> x test_exe!stack
00000296`a543e230 test_exe!Stack = empty
```